# Compilation error with using System.Data.Odbc;

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm just trying to use aspx for the first time and I'm getting a
    CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected
error on line 3.

This is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
<%
    using System.Data.Odbc;
    // Connection
    string connectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=db;User=user;password=pass";
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
    conn.open();
%>
```

I'm unsure on what is wrong with the 'using' line. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of a `<% ... %>` block are *statements* that are put inside of the `Execute` method.
You can't put a `using` directive inside a method.

Instead, you need to use the ASP.Net [`<%@ Import %>` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Odbc" %>
```